# I want user input of array elements and the size of an array as well but, it shows me compilation error what am i missing

Tags: c

I want user input of array elements and the size of an array as well but, it shows me a compilation error what am i missing

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    void main(){
            int i,x,j;
            int index = 1;
            int arr[index]; // this is the place error shows up
/* error says constant expression required*/ 
                scanf("enter the number of elements: %d",&index);
            clrscr();
            for(i=0;i<index;i++){
            printf("Enter element of index no %d",i+1);
            scanf("%d",&x);
                arr[i] = x;
            }
            for(j=0;j<index;j++){
                printf("\n %d ",arr[j]);
            }
    }
```

Comment: It seems your compiler does not support variable length arrays. In any case your program is incorrect because this call of scanf scanf("enter the number of elements: %d",&index); is wrong and moreover after changing the value of index the array size is not changed.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Variable length arrays have been available since C99. They're optional, but almost all implementations support the option.

Comment: I am using classic turbo c

Answer (score 1):

1. Your array `arr` is sized to one element, changing index after the fact does not adjust the size.  In other words, read `index`, then declare `arr`.
2. You try to use `scanf` to print a prompt, but it doesn't work that way.  You need to use `printf()` to write out the prompt.  This was actually was caused the premature exit on my system

Other bonus feedback:

3. `conio.h` and `clrscr()` are windows specific, I believe, so I left it out as I could not test it.
4. Minimized the scope of variables, and eliminated `x` as you can just read directly into `arr[i]`
5. Used `unsigned` instead of `int` when you don't want negative numbers.
6. Formatted code for readability.
7. `main()` by definition returns an `int` so changed it accordingly to resolve the warning with `void main() { ...}`.

Didn't fix:

8. Check the return value from `scanf`, mainly, because I didn't know behavior you want.
9. Check that `index` is reasonable sized.  Variable length arrays (VLA) are dangerous as they will blow your stack if your array is too large.  Stack size is OS specific and at least on Linux it's user configurable. Personally, I don't use VLA in my code and if I cannot statically allocate an array then I use heap allocation via `malloc` and friends.
10. You use name `index` for the number of elements you read.  That term is normally used for loop variable like `i` here that indexed into an array.  I suggest you rename `index` to `n`, `len`, or `size`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned index;
    printf("enter the number of elements: ");
    scanf("%u", &index);
    int arr[index];
    for(unsigned i=0; i<index; i++) {
        printf("Enter element of index no %u: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    for(unsigned i=0; i<index; i++) {
        printf("\n %d ", arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example session:

```
enter the number of elements: 3
Enter element of index no 1: 0
Enter element of index no 2: 1
Enter element of index no 3: 2

 0 
 1 
 2
```

Comment: Hi, Allan thank you for the help! your ans. is a bit high level for me as I am learning to code.                                                                                                                                  
void main()
{
  int i,x,j;
  unsigned index;
  printf("Enter the total num of elements\n");
   scanf("%d",&index);
  int arr[index];   // invalid indirection
  clrscr();
  for(i=0;i<index;i++){
  printf("Enter element of index no %d",i+1);
  scanf("%d",&x);
      arr[i] = x;
  }
  for(j=0;j<index;j++){
   printf("\n %d ",arr[j]);
  }

}